# <class 'psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn'>: column does not exist when JOIN

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, psql

- **python**: 3.9.17
- **psycopg2**: 2.9.7
- **OS**: Ubuntu 20.0
- **postgre**: 12

I did all I can and still this error:

```
2023-09-11 22:45:35,033 ERROR <class 'psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn'>: column u.id does not exist
LINE 1: ...id, u.balance FROM key k JOIN user u ON k.user_id=u.id WHERE...
                                                             ^
```

Python code:

```py
# this all below return the same error
# sql = """SELECT k.user_id, k.custom_rates, u.id, u.balance FROM key k JOIN user u ON k.user_id=u.id WHERE k.key='test'"""
# sql = "SELECT k.user_id, k.custom_rates, u.id, u.balance FROM user u JOIN key k ON k.user_id=u.id WHERE k.key='test'"
# sql = "SELECT k.user_id, k.custom_rates, u.id, u.balance FROM key k INNER JOIN user u ON k.user_id=u.id WHERE k.key='test'"
sql = "SELECT k.user_id, k.custom_rates, u.id, u.balance FROM key k JOIN user u ON k.user_id=u.id WHERE k.key='test'"
cursor.execute(sql)
res = cursor.fetchone()
```

**key** and **user** tables:
[image]

What is mistake?

Comment: Instead of giving a redacted screen capture of actual data, please read [mre] and show an example that others can **copy and paste, without adding or changing anything**, to see the **exact problem, directly** (*including* the code to create a small, sample database that exhibits the problem). If you cannot yet do this, then you have not yet done the [expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) work for a debugging question. Please show as much as possible [as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

key and user are reserved word. Try:

```
FROM "key" k JOIN "user" u
```

Comment: bless you......